# How to get List<> based on ID of another List<> c# MVC 4

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-4

My problem is I could not filter sub list based on `ID` of my another main list. I have 2 lists, `List<main>` and `List<sub>` The `sub` list contain `id` of main.

So far i have done

```cs
@foreach (var main in Model.main_lst)
{
    var FilterdList =  Model.sub_lst.Where(
         x => Model.main_lst.Any(y => y.id == main.id))
    <table>
        @foreach (var sub in FilterdList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => sub.Name)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
var FilterdList =  Model.sub_ls
                      .Where(x => Model.main_lst.Any(y => y.id == x.id)).ToList();
```

Will give you common elements in both the list.

Comment: The question asked for a generic list as the result. This doesn't do that. It would need a `.ToList()` call at the end. If the generic list isn't necessary then the code will be fine as is.

Comment: +1, I second it, thank you :)
OP's requirement doesn't seems to demand a generic list it seems.

Comment: The title says it does `How to get List<> based on ID of another List<> c# MVC 4` however if you look at the code it's not necessary. It's just something I believe you should address in your answer. A simple sentence saying "although you asked for a list in your question, it's not necessary as any IEnumerable should be sufficient" would be a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for can be achieved by

```
 var FilterdList =  Model.sub_lst.Where(x => x.id==main.id);
```

It will give you the list of records from sub list which have same id as that of your main from outer loop.

Comment: The question asked for a generic list as the result. This doesn't do that. It would need a `.ToList()` call at the end. If the generic list isn't necessary then the code will be fine as is.